# error in build.gradle 3: only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy, plugins

I have code in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:1.7.18")
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}
}
```

But when i try add some plugin i get error(i need this plugin for generation asyncApi documentation)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.asyncapi' version '2.3.6'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:1.7.18")
    implementation 'org.json:json:20220924'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

asyncapi {
    schemaDirs = ['src/main/resources/asyncapi'] // Directory where your AsyncAPI schema files are located
    outputFile = 'asyncapi.yaml' // Name of the output AsyncAPI specification file
    version = '2.2.0' // AsyncAPI specification version
}
```

error:

```
Build file '...\build.gradle' line: 3

Could not compile build file '...\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '...\bingo\build.gradle': 3: only buildscript {}, pluginManagement {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
```